# Check if integer contains digit javascript

Tags: javascript

How do you check whether or not an integer contains a digit?

For example:

```
var n = 12;
var m = 34;

n contains 1 // true
m contains 1 // false
```

What's the fastest (performance wise) way to do this without turning the integer into a string?

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that question, it is a different language.

Comment: That's Java, not javascript

Comment: you can iteratively divide by powers of 10 to find every digit. `Math.floor(1234 / 1000) -> 1; Math.floor(234 / 100) -> 2; ...`, etc

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you can't turn it into a string? Otherwise, you need to find Math operations (like the one suggested in the previous comment), which may not be the fastest way to do it (as required).

Comment: `fastest (performance wise)` - are you doing this for millions of numbers at a time? If not, then "performance wise" is irrelevant - nobody is going to notice micro seconds

Comment: Yep - I'm using it for a project euler problem.

Comment: @KadinZhang euler problems are mostly about algorithms not micro-optimisations. If you need to optimise "use string functions" vs "use numeric functions" in your solution then it's likely you have a much better way of solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the following code (if the comments aren't good enough feel free to ask):

```
function contains(number, digit) {
    if (number < 0) { // make sure negatives are dealt with properly, alternatively replace this if statement with number = Math.abs(number)
        number *= -1;
    }
    if (number == digit) { // this is to deal with the number=0, digit=0 edge case
        return true;
    }
    while (number != 0) { // stop once all digits are cut off
        if (number % 10 == digit) { // check if the last digit matches
            return true;
        }
        number = Math.floor(number / 10); // cut off the last digit
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: To get a positive value, use `Math.abs(number)`. No need to test if it is below zero and then multiply by -1.

Comment: I'll edit the comment on that line to include this as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple recursive form -

```js
const contains = (q, p) =>
  p < 10
    ? p === q
    : p % 10 === q || contains(q, p / 10 >>> 0)
    
console.log(contains(1, 12)) // true
console.log(contains(1, 34)) // false
console.log(contains(9, 14293)) // true
console.log(contains(9, 1212560283)) // false
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (n.toString().includes("1")) {

     /// Do something

}
```

Comment: The question states "without turning the integer into a string" which is what `.toString()` is doing here.

Comment: technically, this is correct, the Number `n` remains a number

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
let n = 1234;
let flag = false;
while (n > 0){
    r = n % 10;
    if(r == 1){
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
    n = (n - (n % 10)) / 10;
}
console.log("n contains 1 = "+flag);
```

Comment: Did you try this? It says 1234 does not contain 1. ;)

Comment: then try n >= 0 in while condition

Comment: `n >= 0` would make it an infinite loop

Comment: now it works fine, the JavaScript quotient is a tricky one. I fixed it